# How do I streaming tweets in real time to discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, discord.js

I'm using twitter API so, I can stream tweets to my discord channel.
However, I notice a few things:

- When I turn on the script, it shows me past tweet, I just want real time tweets being sent out.
- Some of the tweets includes retweets and replies and as a result, I would like to filter them.

My Objective is to stream tweets in real time and send those tweet to discord, but I just want the text contents of the tweets and nothing else.

```js
const dest = '####################';

const stream = twitterClient.stream('statuses/filter', {
  follow: '#######', // Twitter ID 
});

stream.on('tweet', tweet => {
  const twitterMessage = `${tweet.text}`
  client.channels.cache.get(dest).send(twitterMessage);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the tweets then have a look to the Twitter  API documentation. https://developer.twitter.com/